# How to make a button of type submit to submit to a different URL? (not to the page it's on)

Tags: html, button, input, icons, submit

I have a form on a page in my web app that I want to submit to a different URL, I am using:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="submit">
```

because I want to embed an icon in the buttons text.

when the button is clicked instead of submitting data to the forms `onsubmit` attribute, it sends it to the current page.

How can I make the button submit to a different path or rather add an icon to the input submit button? (preferably without JavaScript and jQuery because I want the submit method to be POST and not GET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the form `onsubmit` attribute to `action`.

I don't quite understand though why `action` is better than `onsubmit`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways you can create a link to another page.

First, I have an `a` tag acting as a button, a simple `a` tag, and a form set up to direct you to another page. Any of these three methods should work for you.

I am using *target="_blank"* here for the link opens in another tab.

If you want to add icons for styling, I have used [Font Awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome) a lot.

I recommend checking out the different stylings.

```
<a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/' target="_blank"><button> MDN Web Docs</button></a>

<a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/' target="_blank">MDN Web Docs</a>

<form action="https://developer.mozilla.org//" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" value="MDN Web Docs" />
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6wu3v9Lc/3/

#### Font Awesome Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<i class="fas fa-clock"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6wu3v9Lc/5/

Comment: Thanks @A.J.Nock, as you might have noticed, I've already answered my question. Turnes out I was implementing things right only had `onsubmit` instead of `action` in my `<form>` tag.